# .NET - Recommended method to obtain user feedback (WinForm)

Tags: .net, winforms, feedback

I am looking for an effective way to receive feedback from users from within my WinForm application.  I have looked around and found only web-based solutions that require users to go to a web page and fill out forms.

I am looking for something that can be implemented in a way that a user can open a WinForm dialog, fill out the appropriate fields and optionally send a file along with it (an error log in this case).  I have seen many applications implement this but I am not sure how to go about doing it.

The only method I can think of is sending an email from within the application to my e-mail address.  The only problem with this is I would need to hard code some email credentials for the email to be sent but I feel as though this is a slight security risk.

So my question is, are there better methods to receive feedback from users without them having to manually send me an email with feedback and attachment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your WinForms app you could post them to a website, or better yet, a webservice.

Comment: Additionally, if you use this for a bug report scenario, the application might also send along an automatically generated system information report (e.g. msinfo32.exe output).

Answer (score 1):

Post the feedback to your web site using `HttpWebRequest`

Answer (score 1):

Your email server's SMTP port maybe blocked by corporate firewalls. It is best to use a webservice to receive feedback as they work on port 80 which is same as that used for internet browsing and hence never blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You could send the data to a page on a server you have access to, automatically fill out the form and then submit it.  From there you could have a script automatically email you the data and the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution: [Gibraltar Loupe](https://onloupe.com/benefits).

Comment: Indeed, our product is aimed squarely at this scenario.  You can find out more on our site, and just open a live chat with us if we can add any additional information.

Comment: Better yet -- we are now giving away our core framework and log viewer for FREE.  Learn more at http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com

Answer (score 0):

We do use direct SMTP to send us the logs and screenshot when users can have problem. if you are sending within your corp intranet, firewall shouldn't be an issue. Microsoft Enterprise library has some built in functions to send as an email or log to DB